# How does the middle pot's built between flop turn river

Tags: texas-hold-em

I want to know how the pot's built, for a poker app project. Consider an example:

100/200 blinds 3 handed Button SB BB. Cards are dealt, the middle pot is 0 with actions bb 200 and sb 100. On preflop, Button calls SB calls BB checks. Now the middle pot is 600, with latest actions call call check. On the flop, SB raises 200, BB calls Button folds, Now the middle pot is 1000 with latest actions raise 200 call 200 fold. On turn SB raises 200, now middle pot is 1000 with latest actions SB raise 200.

In summary, at the end of every betting round (preflop, flop etc.) the bets are added to the middle pot. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Also small correction when there are no bets out already it is not called a raise but a bet. So SB bet 200 on the turn.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. There is nothing misterious about the pot (unless main-secondary pots are involved). The pot is just the sum of the bets by all players (antes and blinds included)